# Pick out correct statement

Tags: complex-analysis

2.9 Pick out the true statements:

- List item

a. Let f and g be analytic in the disc |z| < 2 and let f = g on the interval
[−1, 1]. Then f ≡ g.

b. If f is a non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients, then it can
be factorized into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors.

c. There exists a non-constant analytic function in the disc |z| < 1 which
assumes only real values.

i was trying and thinking this  about this problem many times but i could not get it, im thinking that  radius of convergence is less than 2, there will beanalytics function less than  2 likely |z| < 1 is assume only real value.

i don't the other option , i have no any other hints solve this question
If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him.

Answer (score 1):

a. is true by the identity theorem.

b. is true by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

c. If $f$ is a non-constant analytic function in the disc $D=\{z: |z| < 1 \}$, then $f(D)$ is open in $\mathbb C$. Hence c. is not true.

Comment: thanks but how f(D) is open  in C  i didn't get this line@ fred